# How to get the type of an object and pass it as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, class, types, interface, refactoring

`ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` and `ClassD` are all implementing `IMyClass` interface.

`myObj` is an instance of one of the classes.

```
private void setObj<T>()
{
    myObj = mycollection.Single(w => w is T);
}

public void Switch()
{
    if(myObj is ClassA)
    {
        setObj<ClassA>();
    }
    else if(myObj is ClassB)
    {
        setObj<ClassB>();
    }
    else if(myObj is ClassC)
    {
        setObj<ClassC>();
    }
    else if(myObj is ClassD)
    {
        setObj<ClassD>();
    }
}
```

How can we refactor the `Switch` method, so that I have something like this:

```
public void Switch()
{
    // How can we know from `myObj`, which class it is and rewrite 
    // the whole Switch method like this
    // X = `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` or `ClassD`

    setObj<X>();

}
```

Comment: Let me confirm I understand the question correctly: you are ok calling Switch method as a generic, with a type passed in? So, `Switch<ClassA>()` is acceptable call? if so, your refactoring suggestion should work just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot pass a generics type parameter as a variable in C#**. However, you can get the type via reflection (`myObj.GetType()`) and pass that as a function parameter from your `Switch()` function to your `setObj()` function, which in turn can be compared in your lambda:

```
    private void setObj(Type type)
    {
        myObj = Objects.Single(o => o.GetType() == type);
    }

    public void Switch()
    {
        Type setToThisType = myObj.GetType();
        setObj(setToThisType);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make `Switch` a generic method too that accepts an `object` of type `T`

```
public void Switch<T>(T obj) where T : IMyClass
{
    setObj<T>();
}
```

The `where T : IMyClass` statement ensures that you can only call `Switch` where `obj` is an `instance` of a `class` implementing `IMyClass`

```
    void Example()
    {
        ClassA objA = new ClassA();
        Switch(objA); //OK;

        ClassX objX = new ClassX();
        Switch(objX); //compile-time error since ClassX doesn't implement IMyClass
    }
```

EDIT: after reading the title, I think you would need to have the parameter `T obj` in the `Switch` method.

Comment: Yep, that's what I originally thought too, hence my comment on the original post... I don't think that's what the OP is asking though, I think they are interested in passing a type from a variable as a generic type param.

Comment: Ah I see, but I think the OP wants to satisfy the condition that `Switch` should only accept a `Type` that `inherits` from `IMyClass` thus I added the `where T : IMyClass`

Answer (score -1):

Try using typeof(ClassA)

```
public void TypeTest(Type t)
{
   if(t.Equals(typeof(ClassA))){
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help with refactoring the method.